# Parse setApplicationId:clientKey: crashing on iOS 7.1.1

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am getting `parse.com` crash before `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called with details as following:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You have to call setApplicationId:clientKey: on Parse to configure Parse.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2fbfcfd3 0x3a79dccf 0x2fbfcf15 0x19a9ab 0x1975d9 0x17650f 0x1926df 0x74345 0x324336ff 0x324c7307 0x324c6e1d 0x324c6b8d 0x324c6b25 0x32418d79 0x3209662b 0x32091e3b 0x320c0cdd 0x32495183 0x324937a3 0x324929f3 0x3249297b 0x32492913 0x3248af89 0x32488971 0x3248886b 0x32488575 0x32487efb 0x3248258b 0x3241e709 0x3241d871 0x32481cc9 0x34a57aed 0x34a576d7 0x2fbc7ab7 0x2fbc7a53 0x2fbc6227 0x2fb30f0f 0x2fb30cf3 0x32480ef1 0x3247c16d 0x134089 0x3acaaab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

(lldb) bt

* thread #1: tid = 0x19a3a1, 0x3ad601f0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x3ad601f0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x3adca796 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 58
    frame #2: 0x3ad10fdc libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 76
    frame #3: 0x3a03fcd6 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 74
    frame #4: 0x3a0586e4 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 252
    frame #5: 0x3a79df64 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 192
    frame #6: 0x3a0561c6 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78
    frame #7: 0x3a055d2c libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 100
    frame #8: 0x3a79de16 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 42
    frame #9: 0x2fb30f84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 640
    frame #10: 0x2fb30cf2 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #11: 0x32480ef0 UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 760
    frame #12: 0x3247c16c UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1136
  * frame #13: 0x001d8088 WorkWire`main(argc=1, argv=0x27d31cd0) + 116 at main.m:18
```

My Code snippet looks like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [Parse setApplicationId:PARSE_APPID clientKey:PARSE_CLIENT_KEY];
```

I have checked everything (like checking provisioning profiles, application ids, parse keys) and the exception keeps coming.

More interesting thing is the application works fine on iOS 8 and the crash is happening on iOS 7 device.

Comment: Have you set an exception breakpoint or looked at the stack trace to see where the call is being made to the parse Api?

Comment: @Paulw11 As I said the app crashes before it enters didfinishlaunchingwithoptions so breakpoints are not coming into play. Stack trace also is not giving any useful information. I have pasted the stack trace too now in the question.

Comment: From similar questions it seems possible that you are calling a Parse function (such as PFUser) on an initialiser somewhere.  An Exception breakpoint should still trigger as it isn't placed on a specific line

Comment: @Paulw11 Well thanks for suggestion. I simply forgot to add that :) However its strange that viewWillAppear of an internal view controller is called before applicationdidfinishlaunching with options.

Comment: Well, I guess if you think about the method name did **finish** launching - if you have specified an initial view controller it has to instantiate that before the app has finished launching...